# Check value of another page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a very simple GreaseMonkey script that will check if the value of another page on the site and return a message accordingly. I can make this work on it's own page but not when looking at another page:

```
(function() { 
    $.get('/active', function(result){       
        if (/1/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
        {
            alert ("Found it!");
        }
    });  
})();
```

How does one reference and check the value of another page?

Comment: If you're calling a third party domain you will need to ensure they return CORS headers in the response, otherwise JS cannot access the returned data due to the [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If it's a request to the local server, use a relative path instead

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah the request is to a local path. Have tried this tho and this doesnt seem to work either. Updated accordingly

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML` relates to the page that you're on. You want to check the returned `result` instead.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks both! Will accept the answer as the clock ticks over!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.body.innerHTML` relates to the page that you're on. You want to check the returned `result` instead.

```
(function() {
  $.get('/active', function(result) {       
    if (/1/i.test(result)) {
      alert ("Found it!");
    }
  });  
})();
```